# Return FormCollection items with Prefix

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can return a subset of a FormCollection with key/values in tact for those items with a certain prefix? I can do it for keys only but I need the keys and values.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this (**tested**):

```
var form = Request.Form;

var prefix = "prefix";

var asDictionary = form.Cast<string>()
    .Where(key => key.StartsWith(prefix))
    .ToDictionary(key => key, key => form[key])
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems a lot of work to do something reasonable straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Assume "form" is your FormCollection, I'd try to use Linq to do something like:

```
FormCollection subset = form.Where(x => x.Key.Contains("YourPrefix_"));
```

I didn't test that :)

Also, you may want to change .Contains() to be .Substring(0,11) == "YourPrefix_", depending on how your keys are named, etc.

Comment: FormCollection does not contain a Where method

Comment: form.AsQueryable().Where(....) maybe? Also, you'll need to have a "using System.Linq;" statement