# Slicing a FormCollection by keys that start with a certain string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a nice *linqy* way of splitting a `FormCollection` into a `Dictionary<string,string>` that contains only those keys that start with a certain string?

*(This question is basically the same as this-> but for C#/FormCollection instead of python [Slicing a dictionary by keys that start with a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558983/slicing-a-dictionary-by-keys-that-start-with-a-certain-string))*

Here's what I came up with to get around the problem:

```
public ActionResult Save(FormCollection formCollection) {
  var appSettings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  var appKeys = formCollection.AllKeys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("AppSettings."));
  foreach (var key in appKeys)
  {
      appSettings[key] = formCollection[key];
  }
...
```

Edit: The problem with this code, is that I have to do it multiple times for different StartsWith strings, and will therefore need to create a 'utility' method to do the above.
It would be nice if it could read in one line like:

```
formCollection.Where(k=>k.Key.StartsWith("AppSettings.");
```

**Background (not necessary to solve the problem):** The context is asp.net mvc, and of a form with a dynamic dictionary of fields.

It's also similar to this question - [Return FormCollection items with Prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109796/return-formcollection-items-with-prefix) - but not quite the same.

And having read this answer [How to build C# object from a FormCollection with complex keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845304/how-to-build-c-object-from-a-formcollection-with-complex-keys) - I started to wonder whether I'd be better off not even using form post, but sending JSON instead.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Note that you should always describe the *problem*. Here it sounds like you're saying "I'm doing something, and this is how I'm doing it. Is there a nice way of doing this?", yet not telling us why your current solution is *not nice*.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to say why it's not nice (with the word "Edit" so it doesn't look like you're complaining about nothing)

Comment: See my answer, and you can always just make that 1 line if needs be. Having said that, making a utility method is probably not the worst idea anyway :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're looking for a "nice" way of taking an existing dictionary, producing a new dictionary with copies of keys+values, for a subset of the keys, some LINQ code will do this nicely:

```
var appSettings = formCollection.AllKeys
    .Where(k => k.StartsWith("AppSettings."))
    .ToDictionary(k => k, k => formCollection[k]);
```

Comment: The only problem is the MVC 'FormCollection', which only implements NameValueCollection - which I should have mentioned/realized doesn't implement IEnumerable - I wonder why, even in MVC3, you would use these custom collection classes that don't implement IEnumerable... it's off topic, but it does seem like a bad design decision...?

Comment: In this day and age with genetics, I would have to agree.

Answer (score -6):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{
     Dictionary<string,object> form = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     collection.CopyTo(form);
     return View();
}
```

Comment: This is an old question, which has already received an accepted answer. Furthermore, your answer does not appear to be correct.

Comment: I use un muy conde works like a charm. Is mvc in case you don't know